# Understanding private set accessors

Tags: c#, struct, private

if i have a struct

```
struct S
{
    int I;
}
```

and in my class I have an accessor like this:

```
class C
{
    public S MyStruct {get; private set;}
}
```

does that mean that I can still modify the values of the struct outside of class C? Could I do
EDIT: made a mistake here:

```
C MyClass = new C();
C.S.I = 5;
```

or are the members of the struct still protected by the private modifier?

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Seems like something you could answer with 5 minutes and a compiler, but no, private setter does not protect the inner bits of the property value.

Comment: I'm no C# developer *but*, doesn't a `struct` mean that a value copy will be taken by the `property` `get` in `class C`? So your code will not modify the data in the `S` instance in class `C`?

Comment: `C MyClass = new MyClass()` what does that do ??

Comment: @Bathsheba Indeed you're right despite you're not c# developer. btw this won't even compile for several reasons :)

Comment: @Bathsheba: Yep!   OP: Why are you using a struct in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A private setter only allows access from within the class.

Example:

```
struct MyStruct { public int I; }
class MyClass { public MyStruct S {get; private set;} }
MyClass C = new MyClass();
C.S = new MyStruct(); // not allowed as private setter
```

When you access a member of `MyStruct` like with `S.I` you have to differentiate between class and struct! If `MyStruct` is a class you will be able to change its value and affect the member variables of `S`. If it is a struct you can not change the value, as `S.I` gives you a copy.

Example (using definitions above):

```
C.S.I = 5; // not allowed as MyStruct is a struct
```

However this is allowed:

```
class MyStruct { public int I; } // it is a class now!
class MyClass { public MyStruct S {get; private set;} }
MyClass C = new MyClass();
C.S.I = 5; // allowed even though setter for S is private
```

Comment: At the time of my comment it really doesn't answered the question. and... now it does :)

Answer (score 1):

The property getter will return a copy of the structure instance by virtue of the fact that it's a value type so, even though you can set the field value of that copy, you can't assign the copy back to the property so you haven't actually affected the property value.  I'm not even sure that the compiler will accept that code for that very reason.  As suggested though, you could have just tested it for yourself.